# Buzzer differences and configurations

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, piezo

I want to understand  the right way to wire a buzzer. I know there are passive and active as well piezo buzzers and magnetic buzzers.  Also, a passive buzzer needs an external source while the active buzzers have a built-in oscillating source.

I see that some circuits use a diode (flyback voltage) or a resistor (discharging) in parallel with the buzzer. From what I have seen the resistor is often used when we want to drive a piezo and a diode when using a magnetic. Is this correct?

I would like an explanation of when to use a diode or a resistor in parallel.

Some circuits don't even use any, just the buzzer by itself.  Is it good practice to place either a resistor or a diode? Some examples are shown below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please I like an explanation of when to use a diode or a resistor in parallel.

Use a diode for a passive magnetic buzzer. Use a resistor for a passive piezo buzzer.

Both both the diode and the resistor serve to restore the passive buzzer to an unenergized state when the transistor switch is off.

Note that the transistors in the schematics provided essentially act as *switches* or as amplifiers with a significant DC component in their output. That is, they do not pass current one way, and then reverse themselves and pass current in the opposite direction. Rather, they alternate between passing current and not passing current.

A piezo transducer, is in many ways similar to a capacitor. If current is passed through a capacitor in one direction only, and never in the opposite direction, the capacitor becomes charged and never discharges. In the case of a passive piezo buzzer, unless current passes in both directions, it will not produce sound (other than an initial click).

The parallel resistor allows the piezo transducer to discharge while the transistor is off.

A passive magnetic buzzer acts in many ways similar to an inductor. When the transistor is on, current flows through the inductor. When the transistor turns off, the inductor attempts to keep the current flowing while it dissipates its stored magnetic energy. A diode in parallel gives the inductor/buzzer a path for such current to flow while dissipating its stored energy.

Edit: Adding [a reference](https://www.cuidevices.com/blog/buzzer-basics-technologies-tones-and-driving-circuits) to address skeptics who have difficulty accepting that

- the purpose of the resistor in parallel to a passive piezo buzzer driven by a common emitter switch is to discharge the capacitance in the piezo device when the transistor is turned off,
- rather than to protect the transistor from (unnecessarily) feared voltage spikes caused by the piezo when the transistor is turned off.

To quote the reference:

> "The diode across the piezo transducer is not required because the inductance of a piezo transducer is small, but a resistor is required to reset the voltage when the switch is open."

Comment: Great answer thank you. Also I was reading that you can use a active buzzer in the same way as a passive. But not the way around. If this right, when driving a active buzzer either magentic or piezo the same way as a passive buzzer, I still need to apply a resitor if piezo or a diode if magentic right?

Comment: If you are driving an active buzzer, you can use a transistor to turn the buzzer on or off, but don't switch the transistor at an audio frequency.

Comment: Like there is still inductive energy stored in an active buzzer when switching it off, which  can exceed the external transistor's Vce max.  (See my answer)

Comment: *"resistor serve to restore the passive buzzer to an unenergized state"* is misleading/incorrect (-1) as the transistor does this alone and much faster (T=L/R is tiny) but can be damaged in the process. But you do need something to protect the transistor from over voltage due to active flyback voltage whether it is internally driven with an oscillator or external.    Why was this answer accepted with errors?

Comment: I disagree. The piezo itself is not conductive. The capacitance cannot be discharged via the transistor. See https://www.cuidevices.com/blog/buzzer-basics-technologies-tones-and-driving-circuits

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 from the article in previous comment. "The diode across the piezo transducer is not required because the inductance of a piezo transducer is small, but a resistor is required to reset the voltage when the switch is open."

Comment: I meant the diode only both types of magnetic buzzers int/ext. was omitted in your answer and the resistor and the diode both dampen  but protect .  They will both stop moving with an open switch. You suggested they diode or resistor is needed to stop them from moving or restore their position.  the magnetic types even have a spring.  The piezo types may be inductively or capacitively coupled with R

Comment: " both serve to restore buzzer to an unenergized state." is technically misleading    Actually transistor leakage will do that for the piezo.   Both parts D and R  serve to  protect Q in the magnetics case and dampen the piezo to shut off quickly. T=RC  unlike magnetics T=L/R where R is the inverse.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 "You suggested they diode or resistor is needed to stop them from moving or restore their position." No,  I did not suggest that the diode or resistor is needed to stop them from moving. However, the resistor is needed in the piezo case to discharge the capacitor consisting of the piezo electrodes, and the piezo as dielectric.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130836/discussion-between-math-keeps-me-busy-and-tony-stewart-ee75).

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic buzzers have a built-in oscillator as do some Piezo buzzers.  A passive types of each are given different names like "Transducer, BUZZER ELEMENT, Piezo Bender"  and have some frequency response over which it can be externally driven.  Often it is driven at the self resonance frequency in a feedback oscillator.

**All magnetic buzzer types (active or passive) need a flyback diode or a current shunt resistor or zener to prevent flyback voltage exceeding the breakdown of an active switch.**

Your choice depends on what you need for power consumption, frequency and loudness. [dBA]  magnetic buzzers require more DC current than Piezo's generally and may operate louder with lower frequencies near 1kHz where our hearing is most sensitive.

When reading the datasheet see what the OEM recommends.
This one does not have a built-in oscillator or diode.
[image]

The circuit you show has a damping resistor instead of a diode, which may be used to suppress the flyback voltage. But there is no citation in your reference images so I cannot comment on details except, that the ideal R will draw more current to absorb stored current from IR=V such that this does not exceed the Vceo breakdown voltage of the transistor. That enables the buzzer to stop slightly faster.

Comment: Thank you, for your response, but my question is when do we need to use a diode or a resistor in parallel with a buzzer.

Comment: Even if the buzzer has an internal oscillator, you can use the same circuit as above to enable it.

Comment: Any questions now?

Comment: I'm not convinced that piezos use the parallel resistor "to suppress the flyback voltage", nor "to absorb stored current from IR=V such that this does not exceed the Vceo breakdown voltage of the transistor" but to discharge the capacitance in the piezo.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy  What I said was "damping resistor instead of a diode,"  .  This is another way to shutoff quickly and reduce flyback. I never indicated that was for a Piezo rather the diagram shown with a magnetic coil buzzer speaker.   T=L/R and T=RC so low R makes C dissipate fast and low R for magnetics dissipates slow but clamps with a diode or limits voltage V=IR. Got it?